# Open Chrome with selenium as user

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome

Currently having a problem to open Chrome with Selenium using my default browser. I have specified the correct path to my user data profile through the AddArgument function. (The one specified when i visit chrome://version/ logged in). However no matter how i am not able to access my default chrome instance where i am logged in. This is the code i have used.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        
        options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 2");
       
        ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has a User data directory for storing profiles. Inside this directory, multiple profiles can be maintained. There are two arguments that can be used

1. user-data-directory
2. profile-directory

If only `user-data-directory` is specified then a `Default` directory inside the same would be used. If `profile-directory` is specified then that directory inside the `user-data-directory` is used

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried switching to profile-directory instead. However it was unsuccessful. It now opens a window where i may choose to browse as Guest and gives me an option to log in as user. Any ideas what can be the issue? this is the changed code: options.AddArgument(@"profile-directory=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 2");